# VB.NET copy a 2-dimenion List into a one dimension list

Tags: vb.net, list

In my original code I have a list object containing 2 columns, `Word` and `Percent`. I sort the list but only want to return the list containing just the Word

Here is some example code broken down into something simple:

```
Public Function SortMyWords() as list(of string)
    Dim Words As WordsToSort
    Dim ListofWords As New List(Of WordsToSort)

    Words.Word = "John"
    Words.Percent = "10"
    ListofWords.Add(Words)

    Words.Word = "Robert"
    Words.Percent = "1"
    ListofWords.Add(Words)

    ListofWords = ListofWords.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Percent).ToList()
End Sub

Public Structure WordsToSort
    Public Word As String
    Public Percent As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal _word As String, ByVal _percent As String)
        Word = _word
        Percent = _percent
    End Sub
End Structure
```

At the end of the `SortMyWords` function, I want to return just the `Word` column back as a list, I'm not sure if I can do this direct - i.e.
`Return Listofwords(column Word)` or whether I need to copy my `ListofWords` into a new list, just containing the Column Word - something like this (which doesn't work)

```
Dim Newlist As New List(Of String)
Newlist.AddRange(ListofWords(Words.Word))
Return NewList
```

Any suggestions on whether I should do this completely differently (and better) would be really appreciated as I am trying to get my head around objects and although I use them all the time, I'm new to structures and list objects.

Thanks for any help, this has been driving me crazy for an hour now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're close. Try:

```
ListOfWords
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Percent)
    .Select(Function(x) x.Word)
    .ToList()
```

If you prefer, you can also use the LINQ syntax:

```
(from w in ListOfWords
    orderby w.Percent ascending
    select w.Word).ToList()
```

Note that the return type is a `List(Of String)` and not a `List(Of WordsToSort)` anymore. So you cannot assign it back to the variable `ListOfWords` again like you do in your sample code.

Comment: I tried to return ListofWords but I am getting an error saying "Value of type 'List(Of WordsToSort)' cannot be converted to 'List(Of String)' - its as if the listofwords it still a single-dimension list, I can also still fetch variables  from the percent column, i.e. 
msgbox(ListofWords(1).Percent)

I'm not sure how to use the Linq but I wouldn't mind knowing as I am quite familiar with SQL and its very sql like

Comment: `List(Of String)` seems to be the correct return type for your method. So just type a `Return` before one of the queries above. Btw. `List(Of )` is always one-dimensional. It's just a plain list. Having a `List(Of T)` where `T` is a class with properties does not make a list multidimensional.

Comment: You're a star - thank you very much indeed - i'd upvote your answer but I dont have enough points yet, so a personal thank you will have to do - cheers

Comment: Not enough points to mark an answer as solution? Did not know that this is a thing ...

Comment: @Waescher They [can't upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4421/147640) because they lack [the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), but they can accept. They did not probably take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - the changes to code work wonderfully, though I am struggling to get the list to be order by in percent - descending order so the highest matches show first i.e.  ListofWords.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Percent)
            Return ListofWords.Select(Function(x) x.Word).ToList() its still coming out in alphabetical order, of the word, rather than the percent order but showing word

Comment: GOT IT !!!  ListofWords = ListofWords.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Percent).ToList()

Comment: Now that returns a sorted List(Of WordsToSort), I thought you just wanted the words as List(Of String) sorted by percent. But okay, that's fine 

Comment: To the prior comment: OrderBy() and OrderByDescending() will not sort the list it was called on, it returns a sorted result which you can continue to work with.